# subir calidad de imagen codificada en base64

Tags: javascript, php

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

- Estoy realizando una app en laravel, en la cual capturo fotografias desde un dispositivo móvil de alta gama, adicianal a eso utilizo cropperjs para recortarla, lo que intento hacer es mandar la imagen en base64 para reducir su tamaño y almacenarla en el servidor, actualmente me reduce el peso y por ende la calidad siginificativamente y solo quiero perder un poco de calidad, he estado investigando y se podria manejar como unos margenes con quality pero hasta ahora no tengo éxito, si alguien me puede ayudar estaria muy agradecido.

Este es el codigo con el que reduzco la calidad, envio la imagen en base64:

```js
function resizeBase64Img(base64, newWidth, newHeight) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.style.width = newWidth.toString() + "px";
                canvas.style.height = newHeight.toString() + "px";
                let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                let img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = base64;
                img.onload = function() {
                    context.scale(newWidth / img.width, newHeight / img.height);
                    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
                }
            });
        }
        
        
        resizeBase64Img(base64data, 300, 150).then((result) => {
                        $(inputBase64).val(result);
                    });
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es no perder calidad entonces para que le reduces tanto el tamaño? Una camara de alta gama y cambias la imagen a 300px por 150px?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que muestro la imagen en un contenedor pequeño, solo quiero reducir la calidad para poder guardarla, antes me guardaba completa y normal, ahora si agrando el tamaño  300px y 150px se sale del contenedor y la imagen sigue con la misma calidad

Comment: cual es el objetivo de disminuir la calidad ???

Comment: ¿Y quién te dijo que usar Base64 comprime o reduce el tamaño de una imagen? Sucede todo lo contrario, [su tamaño aumenta hasta un 25%](https://www.keycdn.com/support/image-base64-encoding#file-size).